# installing jenkins with docker

Tags: build

i am using a system which runs on ubuntu 14.04 when i try to install docker it is been installed ,
but i need to build a image using jenkins and docker,
when i run the below command it changes to docker ubuntu ,

docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash

but i am not able to install jenkins over here ,
please let me know what are the steps that can be done .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What's stopping you from being able to install Jenkins? If you've run the Ubuntu Docker container as you say, you should be able to install Jenkins the same as if it were any Ubuntu machine.

But this isn't really the way to build images, you should use a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) with a series of instructions of what the image should be.

Better yet, why not use [the existing Jenkins image on the Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/)? This is an official image, created by those who create Jenkins. This should be the easiest way by far to get started with Jenkins in Docker (and the *right way*).